# Compare every column of TWO tables and show which one is greater?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables namely `STUDENT` and `COLLEGE`

STUDENT table

```
 Student_id   | GPA  | backlog | internship        
    stu_a1    | 6.72 |   1     |   1
```

COLLEGE table

```
College | min_gpa | min_backlog | min_internship    
clg_a   | 9.60    |     0       |  1    
clg_b   | 7.60    |     1       |  1    
clg_c   | 4.60    |     2       |  0
```

above are minimum requirement of college.

*note: both tables are different*

so what I want is to compare every data in `student` table with `college` table and show which college suits the student according to their data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a join -- but with an inequality.  For instance:

```
select s.*, c.*
from students s join 
     colleges c
     on s.gpa >= c.min_gpa and
        s.backlog >= c.min_backlog and
        s.internship >= c.min_internship;
```

Comment: I want to fetch for single student only how can I achieve that

Comment: To fetch for a single student only you can attach a where clause at the end of the query. In your case: where student_id = 'stu_a1'. It is a good idea to use an ID like you do, but instead of using a string value you should use a number that automatically increments to ensure that all your records are uniquely identifiable. It is also common for the id column to simply be named 'id'.